# Why do the links start with //?

Tags: hyperlink

I am wondering why some starts with "//"? Is it a shortcode for "http://"? 
E.g On the HTML5 boilerplate, I see the inclusion of the jQuery library as follows:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can I use `//` instead of `http://` on any sites or do I need to pay for this service extra?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two forward slashes in a url/src/href attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with // means you keep the protocol.
If you are serving pages both as http and https this is handy as to not change the protocol when linking.
Read more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646435/521554