# $ not defined ajax request in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I am trying to send a php file some values using ajax but in the call for ajax I am getting the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

at the beginning line for the ajax request as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'program3.php',
  data: {
    player1name: player1name.value,
    player2name: player2name.value,
    playtopoints: playtopoints.value,
    delay: delay.value,
    numgames: numgames.value,
    gamesplayed: gamesplayed.value,
    p1turn: p1turn.value,
    p2turn: p2turn.value,
    p1total: p1total.value,
    p2total: p2total.value
  },
  success: function (data) {
    rolling = data;
  }
});
```

I first thought that it might need the refrence to ajax so i added the following line before the javascript on the html page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but i am still getting the erro can anyone offer any insight?

Also i have the data variables all defined as follow:

```
var player1name = document.JForm.p1name.innerHTML;
```

is that the correct way to assign them?

Comment: is it wrapped in script tags correctly?

Comment: and wrapped in `$(document).ready`?

Comment: ^^ or at least in a function that is called after `ready`

Comment: Dragon should i put the javascript tags inside the ajax script tags?
hexacyanide the file are stored within the same directory on the server i am using
@atomman and Jeffman what are you saying should be wrapped in $(document).ready

Comment: no such thing as "ajax script tags"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `src` on your script tag is invalid—at least if you're [not running this from http or https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute).  Replace

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: well take a look at this, this has nothing to do with his problem at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute double slashes helps to avoid http/https mess, it will work for both.

Comment: It should have worked with just the slashes. See this post..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute

Comment: @CharlieMartin: Not if you're using your local file system; you must specify the protocol in that scenario.

Comment: `//` will try to use the same protocol of the current page, if its `file://` or `ftp://` it will fail.

Comment: @Charlie - I actually didn't know about `//` though - thanks for the info.

Comment: Ah yes, the local file protocal fails. Nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably accessing the file locally, which won't work with a protocol-relative script tag.

```
<!-- access from http resolves to this -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- local access resolves to this -->
<script src="file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The file wouldn't have existed locally, and the script would've never been loaded. Therefore, the variable `$` would then be undefined.