# jquery lib is not including

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i have developed my plugin and i got some strange problem. when i am including **Jquery lib** file with this code

```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it's working fine but when i am including **Jquery Lib** with this code it's not working

```
   <script src="<?php echo plugins_url(); ?> /kp_contactus/js/jquery.js"> </script>
```

the path is proper i have checked and local **Jquery lib** version is `jQuery v1.10.2`

i am getting console error is...

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function ?page_id=19:108
>   (anonymous function)

can anybody suggest what's going wrong with it?

```
   $('#contact').validate({
        /* Making ajax request on successfull submition*/
       submitHandler : function (form){
           var name=$("#firstname").val();
           var email=$("#useremail").val();
           var contact=$("#mobile").val();
           var type=$("#type").val();
           var msg=$("#message").val();
           $("#send").attr("disabled",true).html("Sending");
           var data = { 'name': name, 'email' : email, 'contact' : contact, 'type' : type, 'msg' : msg };
           $.ajax({
               url : '<?php echo plugins_url();?>'+'/kp_contactus/kp_contact_config.php',
               type : 'POST',
               data : {contact:JSON.stringify(data)},
               success : function (msg)
               {
                  $("#info").fadeIn().html(msg).fadeOut(5000);
                  $("#send").attr("disabled",false).html("Send");
                  $("#contact").find("input").val("");
                  $("#contact").find("textarea").val("");
               }
           })
       },
```

Comment: Show us the pluginsurl function please, I also suggest making it into a string constant.

Comment: Where r u using $ ? show code

Comment: @Mazzy it's inbuilt function of wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing jQuery code for WordPress, I often use `jQuery('#getId')` instead of `$('#getId')` and it works, have you tried that?

Here is an interesting and [brief article](http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/) that can help explain it.

Comment: now i am getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. There is a possibility that its conflicting so use **jQuery** keyword instead of **$**

with reference to your this comment "**now i am getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined**" this implies that the library is not being found double check for this.

Also as pointed by **Zaheer** put in http:// (As pointed out by others not required necessarily)

Comment: i am getting this error after changing $ with JQuery "i am getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

Sometime different libraries conflict over `$`.

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict(); // releases $ from jQuery

jQuery( document ).ready(  // you must need to use jQuery here

 function( $ ) { // you passed $ as a parameter for jQuery

   // Use jQuery code with $ keyword
    $( "div a" ).show();
 });

// Use other library with $ keyword
$("content").style.display = "none";

</script>
```

Comment: well caught, u have great eyes :)

Comment: It works with //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js as well.

This previous stack can explain a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute

Comment: without http:// it's working... i am using this path in my all project and i didn't get issue till now...