# Library links without HTTP, what's the difference?

Tags: http, hyperlink

I have noticed that a lot of places that offer shared libraries are not including the `http://` in front of the link. Example, cdnjs and google libraries.

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1140/2.0/1140.css
```

My questions are:

Why? And what's the difference between this?

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1140/2.0/1140.css
```

and this?

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1140/2.0/1140.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving of the http: means that the include will use the same protocol as the page that includes the file - so if you are running your site on https and you embed your external resources using http:// you will see a lot of "unsafe resources" or "blocked resources" 
If you embed them using // instead they will be fetched using https on an https site - which means they won't be blocked and not considered unsafe.

Take a look here: [Two forward slashes in a url/src/href attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute/9646435#9646435) which explains this in great detail

Comment: Thank you! Although the other answer is also correct. You answered it first.

Answer (score 1):

It'll use `http` or `https` for the link to the library depending on the context of the referencing page.