# Where is stated the links starting with // are syntactically correct?

Tags: html

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute), that explains that links starting with // are used to maintain the procotol (http or https).

Is this something defined in a standard or RFC? Or is it just a hack implemented by browsers? I think it's useful, but before using it I want to make sure it is understood by all browsers.

Comment: Yes, you can use it for all browsers.

Comment: The question links to an old question, which is itself a duplicate of an older question, which has an accepted answer, which cites the relevant Internet-standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

From 4.2:

> relative-ref  = relative-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
> ```
>   relative-part = "//" authority path-abempty
> ```

And:

> 5.4.1.  Normal Examples
>
> ...
>
> `"//g"           =  "http://g"`

So it is part of the standard, and used my all current browsers.

Comment: RFC 1808 was obsoleted by RFC 3986 in 2005.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: You are right. Updated.