# ignore url mod-rewrite via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

i use Prestashop and force https for all url.

I need to add script with this url: 
**src="//c.imedia.cz/js/retargeting.js"**
i need url keep like this in html.

but htaccess seems change it to 
**src="https://c.imedia.cz/js/retargeting.js"**
which doesn't work then.

i tried to add Rewrite rule to prevent override this url

```
RewriteRule retargeting\.js$ - [L,NC]
```

Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

`htaccess` does not change the `src` in your HTML. The **browser** will replace `//` with the protocol that is used in the request. i.e. `https`. It's commonly referred to as `protocol relative URL`.

[More info in this answer about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute/9646435#9646435)

So if you don't want it to use `https` then you should explicitly set it as `http`. That will however cause mixed content when served over `https` and modern browsers will probably block it. So if you force `https` then **ALL** your resources have to be `https` as well or it will be blocked and not loaded even using `http`.

So then you should get a wildcard SSL certificate for your subdomains so that your resources can be served as `https` as well.