# Images with protocol-relative source URLs don't load in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I use the following syntax in my application so that images are loaded over https or http depending upon how the page was loaded.

```
<img src="//path_to_image.jpg">
```

This works fine in Chrome but firefox does not display any images.

What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: basic debugging: check your server's access log to see what each browser's requesting (if anything).

Answer (score 2):

The // use to support multiple protocol (i.e. `http` or `https`), these type of URL is known as "protocol relative URLs" and use with complete domain name. Mostly CDN url are used with //.

If you are planning to use // make sure you use full domain url (i.e. //xyz.com/images/path_to_image.jpg). If you just want to use relative path from the root then use single slash (i.e. /)

Following like help you to understand // usage

[Two forward slashes in a url/src/href attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Using `//` will only work with a full URL ('//yourhost.tld/directory/path_to_image.jpg'). In your case one slash `/`, should be enough!