# Redirect to an other website

Tags: html, href, redirect

i'm trying to create a link that redirect to another website like this :

```
<a target="_blank" href="exemple.com/test">hello</a>
```

but it redirect me to `mywebsite.com/exemple.com/test`

How can i make it work ? :)

**EDIT :** Correct answer was to use `//` before url

```
href="//exemple.com/test"
```

Comment: Please read the entire question before saying it's duplicate....

Comment: _“i need to make it work with this url”_ - you can’t, because that’s not how URLs work. `exemple.com/test` _is_ a relative URL, that refers to a file or folder named `test` inside a folder named `exemple.com` inside the current directory. So your question makes very little sense to begin with.

Comment: You did not understand then. exemple.com/test is another website. If you put my url inside google search bar it will find my website.

Comment: @JérémyMisiti — The Google Search bar is doing a *search* not following a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
<a target="_blank" href="//exemple.com/test">hello</a>
```

Comment: Yes this is what i need ! But it redirect me to https and my website is an http :s

Comment: I will. You'r the one who understood the question and responding great ! But i need to make it work with http before it :)

Comment: Ok just a min  ...

Answer (score 1):

You are giving relative URL. Give absolute url instead to achieve your goal.

e.g.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.exemple.com/test">hello</a>
```

Comment: I know. But i need to make my url work like it is.

Comment: @JérémyMisiti – Your URL is *wrong*. Plain and simple. Fix the URL.

Comment: My url work. i'm creating a redirect service i need to have the smallest url possible. So i need to make my exemple.com url work.

Comment: @JérémyMisiti – The error recovery that browsers perform when you type a URL with the scheme missing into the address bar does not get run when you have a URL somewhere that a relative URL would make sense.

Comment: I used `//exemple.com/test` and it worked. So there's senses.

Comment: @JérémyMisiti — Congratulations. You have changed the URL as described in the answer to the question you claimed was not a duplicate.

Comment: But i need to make this redirect to http and not https

Comment: Check this. Usage of // . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute

Comment: If you want to explicitly redirect it to http. Why can't you write 'http' in the URL?

Comment: i need to make my url as small as possible