# Opencart admin URL shortner (Hide index.php?route="")

Tags: php, html, opencart, opencart-3

I want to hide index.php?route=""&user_token="" showing on my opencart admin page. Is it possible to hide this and show something like instead of admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard&user_token="" it shows only admin/dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple and fast way to do that. I even tried to look for a solutions, seems like nobody before tried to do so. `user_token` is an OpenCart security token, a GET-parameter. To remove it we should completely rewrite OC admin authorization core.

There is one solution, a little bit savage. If you are Ok with the idea that all your admin pages will have the same address (the address won't change during the navigation), so lets try it.

In the root folder of your website (where **index.php**, **confing.php**, **.htaccess** are) create file **dashboard.php**. With following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      WhiteDot Sports Dasboard
    </title>
    <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    iframe {
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="//whitedotsports.co.uk/admin/"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now your admin panel will be accessible from https://whitedotsports.co.uk/dashboard.php.

Comment: re your final comment `//whitedotsports.co.uk/admin/` [will work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute)

Comment: Thanks @Martin, corrected it in the answer. Forgot about that in `iframe` it's also works.