# No matter what - Reference error $ is not defined (jQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

no matter how i do this i cant get rid of this error. I am trying to make a few draggable divs but i get the error 'Reference error: $ is not defined'. I checked through my code, all OK. So i tested running jQuerys examplecode for draggable divs, still, same error. Here's the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
       <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
       <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <style>
   #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
   </style>
   <script>
   $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
   });
   </script>
   </head>
    <body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is my own code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Text demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".groupItem").draggable();
  });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="newsFeeder" class="groupItem">

        <div class="itemHeader">Feeds</div>
        <div class="itemContent">
            <ul>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>

                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="news" class="groupItem">
        <div class="itemHeader">News</div>
        <div class="itemContent">

            <ul>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="shop" class="groupItem">
        <div class="itemHeader">Shopping</div>
        <div class="itemContent">
            <ul>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>

                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="links" class="groupItem">
        <div class="itemHeader">Links</div>
        <div class="itemContent">
            <ul>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>

                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="images" class="groupItem">
        <div class="itemHeader">Images</div>

        <div class="itemContent">
            <ul>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
                <li>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code runs fine for me, apart from the missing HTML tag at the start looking dubious.

Comment: Take a look at Net(work)  tab in the dev tools of your browser to see, if jQuery really is loaded.

Comment: I suspect this will turn out to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503946/shorthand-http-as-for-script-and-link-tags-anyone-see-use-this-before

Comment: @Quentin In OP's "own code" there's the protocol part though.

Comment: Please don't re-write your question according to suggestions in the comments or answers. That will make unclear, why an answer/comment was posted. Instead you can add an edit part explaining what is fixed so far. If the problem changes totally, please ask a new question. Though now looking your code, you haven't linked to jQuery-UI at all ... This means you've introduced a whole new problem  with your edit. I've rolled the post back to the previous version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace jquery link with this one and you are on:
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js

i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using the minified version isn't necessary, and not ideal during development

Comment: Thanks I will take care of this and can you please explain me why use of minified version is not ideal?

Comment: Okay @AjayMakwana i did like you said, and also uppdated jQuery to 1.12, now im getting error '$(...).draggable is not a function', any ideas here?

Comment: @DouglasPettersson now your jquery is conflict with the jQuery UI