# How is url without protocol differs from a simple one?

Tags: url, browser

I often see people use urls like below for CDN resources.

```
 <script src="//site.domain.com"></script>
```

I wonder how it's different for browser if it was specified like "https://site.domain.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "keep the same scheme" than the actual document.

See [shorthand http:// as // for script and link tags? anyone see / use this before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503946/shorthand-http-as-for-script-and-link-tags-anyone-see-use-this-before)

**UPDATE** : correct link.

Comment: Recursive link?)