# Browser support for "//domain.com"

Tags: browser, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it valid to replace  with // in a <script src=“…”>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Do all browsers support referencing without the leading `http:` or `https:`?

For example:

```
<a href="//example.com/account">
<img src="//example.com/image.gif">
```

Which should automatically use whatever connection the user currently has (HTTP or HTTPS)

Can I get into trouble if I use this everywhere in my app?

Basically, I want to keep "absolute" URLs consistent, without having to make sure I added `https:` if the user is on a secure connection (so he doesn't get warnings), and `http:` when he is not on a secure connection (so assets load faster — no HTTPS handshaking).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not count Internet Explorer as a browser, yes, almost every general browsers supports this.

**Now seriously:** I didn't try it in IE, but every general browser does support this!

Comment: Using https for everything, including images/css, has the benefit of not triggering 'mixed content'-type messages.

Comment: What about mobile safari and android browsers?

Comment: @Dan: Hmm. I'll try it with Xperia X10 mini and let you know

Comment: Great! Regarding https for images/css, you sometimes need it. If you have a logged in user who is on https, the assets on that page should be loaded with https too, so he doesn't get security warnings.