# External Javascript tag using absolute link without protocol

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, src

The Google Translate tool sample has a script tag like this:

```
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js"></script>
```

Note that the http is missing. I am assuming that this way it automatically uses http or https according to the parent page (does it?). It also saves five bytes. I've never seen this before. Does this work for all kinds of href and src attributes? How about on pages that were loaded using file:// ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Comment: @Gaby: Thanks, it is a duplicate. Will delete after someone clarifies the file:// part (which does not seem to be answered there)

Comment: OTOH: After someone clarified this, it is probably better not to delete it. Voting to close instead.

Answer (score 2):

The protocol relative URL. Further reading here. Read the comments too.

http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: Correct, it looks like it doesn't work. Also I ran into a problem (noted in the comments on that blog post) where an HTML email received by Outlook using this protocol caused Outlook to search for the file locally.