# Weird asset url without 'http' in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 3.1.1, Ruby 1.9.3, `asset_host='assets.foo.com'`

This

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'home' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'home' %>
```

produces

```
<link href="http://assets.foo.com/assets/home-f803345a3514568545f88946a69d6bab.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="//assets.foo.com/assets/home-da846573d17e8a062b5a8d6c122abc97.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can't figure out why the script's src is malformed.

I see similar URLs without the protocol schema in CSS file, as the result of the `image-url()` Sass helper.

Where should I look to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not malformed. Most modern browsers these days will automatically put in the protocol you're using when it sees the `//`. It's called relative protocol resolution.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http/550073#550073) answer as well as [RFC 3986 Section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2)