# Twitter share button only shows up as hyperlink

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to add the Twitter Share button to my website. I've gone to https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet and added the code to my html, but the "button" only shows up as a hyperlink.

Can someone tell me how to make the button look exactly like the normal twitter button that shows up on other sites?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make it work by changing the code that says

```
id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js
```

to

```
id;js.src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you so much. Can you explain why that made a difference? I'm just learning how to do all this.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Twitter is explicit about using the "//" syntax. [They explain here](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/ssl-support-tweet-button-and-follow-button) that it is for automatic switching between 'http' and 'https' pages. You can read more about the '//' syntax at [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src=“http://…”>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http). It is reported there that it is supported in all browsers. So not only is it correct, it's a good idea. Your original problem must have been elsewhere.

Comment: @MarkStosberg: Thanks for following up with this update. I am not much of a JS guy and when I faced this issue, "it worked for me" by following what I had mentioned above. Also this kind of a URI being valid was not known to me at that time (now I know thanks to your link.) I am sure many people will face this issue and using my hack will "fix it" for them. Going forward, how do we solve the "real underlying problem"? (and what could it be really?)