# Content security policy blocking requests to *://www.google.com/recaptcha/api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, recaptcha, content-security-policy

[In light of this link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107538) ,
it would seem inline scripts such as are used for inserting a recaptcha object in the page, via

```
<script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key">
</script>
<noscript>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=your_public_key"
     height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
<textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
     value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

or via

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

with

```
Recaptcha.create("your_public_key",
"element_id",
{
  theme: "red",
  callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
}
```

);

I always get some complaint about the content security policy, despite my manifest.json apparently allowing urls' like http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js

Am I missing something really obvious that makes this whole question crazy?

Answer (score 4):

I just spent two hours fighting with this. For me, and I think for this example as well, the problem lies in the `src` attribute; that is, in the `http:`. Changing the references as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
     src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key">
              ^  v
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=
     height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

fixed the problem. Basically, you're attempting to access the google api with an unsecure connection, and certain browsers (e.g., Chrome) don't render insecure content by default.

Answer (score 1):

In a Chrome extension, the non-secure `http` cannot be whitelisted via the CSP.
[The documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H2-3) states:

> ### Relaxing the default policy
>
> (...) If, on the other hand, you have a need for some external JavaScript or
> object resources, **you can relax the policy to a limited extent by
> whitelisting specific HTTPS origins** from which scripts should be
> accepted. **Whitelisting insecure HTTP resources will have no effect.**
> This is intentional, because we want to ensure that executable
> resources loaded with an extension's elevated permissions is exactly
> the resource you expect, and hasn't been replaced by an active network
> attacker. **As man-in-the-middle attacks are both trivial and
> undetectable over HTTP, only HTTPS origins will be accepted.**

Comment: I have this same problem. What can we do then?

Comment: @Vigneshwaran What's your problem? Consider creating a new question with specific details if needed.

Comment: My chrome extension uses Google Feed apis. Those apis call some other Javascripts over 'HTTP' so you know there's no solution for me. `only HTTPS origins will be accepted` I'm solving it by moving to different feed api provider.

Comment: @Vigneshwaran "Call other JavaScript" -> Using XMLHttpRequest? If yes, then you can fix the issue by adding a valid match pattern to the manifest, e.g. `"permissions": ["http://api.somedomain.com/*"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make all your resource calls protocol relative urls. Basically remove any http: or https: and just use //

More info here 
http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

and here [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)