# Google ReCaptcha Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com"

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I'm not sure why this is happening, and it isn't the usual, common error of:

> **Uncaught SecurityError:** Block a frame with origin.

The error I'm getting is:

> **Uncaught DOMException:** Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I'm following Google's instructions on how to enable ReCaptcha, but it isn't working for me!

```
// top of the page
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
// then somewhere in the bottom
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="@Model.Register.CaptchaSiteKey"></div>
```

My `CaptchaSiteKey` is being loaded (I debugged and checked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The same-origin policy is an important concept in the web application
>   security model. Under the policy, a web browser permits scripts
>   contained in a first web page to access data in a second web page, but
>   only if both web pages have the same origin. An origin is defined as a
>   combination of URI scheme, hostname, and port number. This policy
>   prevents a malicious script on one page from obtaining access to
>   sensitive data on another web page through that page's Document Object
>   Model.

In other word: `recaptcha` is an Remote Script resource, and for security issues, your web server not allowing to use external resources code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

To allow any resource to access your resource, you can specify:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

To allow https://www.google.com to access your resource, you can specify:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.google.com

Comment: The question here becomes, what resource is the recaptcha iframe trying to access on my server? There is no mention of such a requirement in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/).

Answer (score 0):

As explained by the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014899/1853802, change all the http(s) protocols on your page to //

e.g.

```
<script src="http://example1.com"></script> => <script src="//example1.com"></script>

<link href="https://example2.com" /> => <link href="//example2.com />
```

This solved it for me.

NB: Remember to clear your cache afterwards.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. I have: //www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js. But it is calling: https:/ /www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor? <= is the problem here.