# Facebook Javascript SDK 404 - //connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to include a simple Like button on my page using HTML 5. I'm including the Javascript SDK on my page like mentioned in the docs but I get a 404 error on the URL. "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"

Here's my code : http://snipt.org/ujEg8

Here's the channel file code : http://snipt.org/ujEh4

I don't understand whats going on. Please help.

Thanks
smaira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely just need to add the right protocal before the // call, for example:

```
http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
```

See here for more info on the real issue: [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)