# Div selected state

Tags: javascript, css, html, state, selected

Hi people @stackoverflow,
I'm currently trying to make a nav bar with the function of 'selected-state'.
I got it to work nicely with jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/uphem/U7NLM/ but the selected-state somehow isn't working when I create a html out of this.
It's pretty much an exact copy of what I had in jsfiddle.
I tried to embed the jquery as a file and that didn't work either.

I can't seem to figure out why it's not working..
Please help!

```
<html>
<head>

<title>selected state test</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.menu_button').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected')
    })​
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.menu_button {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: #666;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px dotted #e5e5e5;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_button:hover {
    color: #f26d7d;
}

.menu_button:active {
    color: #ccc;
}

.menu_button.selected {
    background-color: #ccc;
}​
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="menu_button">button 1</div>
<div class="menu_button">button 2</div>
<div class="menu_button">button 3</div>
<div class="menu_button">button 4</div>​

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: was the missing "http:" from the script src a typo when moving it here, or when trying the script?

Comment: @SReject I forgot to mention but I tried that too. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery here you will see that they don't inclue it. I think it's because without "http:" you could utilize not only for http but also for https.

Comment: then remove the "//" from it :)

Comment: "//" means use same protocol as parent. If you request that in http it uses http for request and same thing for https. Just, it is not supported by older browsers.

Comment: To expand a bit, using the double leading slashes (`//`) is [protocol relative scheme](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). This will work fine (and recommended!) if the file is actually being served from a server, but will fail if using the `file://` protocol as the browser will request: `file://ajax.googleapis.com...`.

Comment: Yea, I had to add http: to it. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the jQuery code [only after the page is loaded](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29), like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu_button').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected')
    })
});
</script>
```

as well, Could it be that your jQuery import call is wrong?

Try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

for more information about when and how to use `//` instead of `http://` read [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

I've tried your code and it worked for me after that change

Answer (score 1):

If you are working offline your jQuery call is wrong.

Use this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
<html>
<head>

<title>selected state test</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".menu_button").click(function(e) {
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    });
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.menu_button {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: #666;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px dotted #e5e5e5;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_button:hover {
    color: #f26d7d;
}

.menu_button:active {
    color: #ccc;
}

.menu_button.selected {
    background-color: #ccc;
}​
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="menu_button">button 1</div>
<div class="menu_button">button 2</div>
<div class="menu_button">button 3</div>
<div class="menu_button">button 4</div>​

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
    $(document).ready{
        $('.menu_button').click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected')
        })​;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with your src:

```
// this directs to yourdomain.com/ajax....
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

//Instead use one of the following
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>selected state test</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.menu_button').click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected')
        });
    });


</script>

<style type="text/css">
.menu_button {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: #666;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px dotted #e5e5e5;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_button:hover {
    color: #f26d7d;
}

.menu_button:active {
    color: #ccc;
}

.menu_button.selected {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="menu_button">button 1</div>
<div class="menu_button">button 2</div>
<div class="menu_button">button 3</div>
<div class="menu_button">button 4</div>

</body>
</html>
```