# Hide P tag not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm teaching myself Javascript (with Jquery) and I'm simply trying to do a show/hide on click function.

Now, I'm doing it with Sublime Text 2 and I'm trying to view it in browser by local host – I'm also doing this with HTML5 Boilerplate.

Below is my code.

To call Jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('p').hide();
});

  </script>
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="paragraphAnchor">click me</a>
 <p>This is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a test</p>
```

I'm doing all of this within my HTML document. Not best practice but I thought I'd start small.

Now I do this, and the text isn't even hidden.

Why is this?

UPDATE:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

  <!-- CSS concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!-- end CSS-->

  <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
  $('p').hide();
  $(a#paragraphAnchor).click(function()
  {
    $('p').show();
  });
});

  </script>
</head>

<body>


 <a href="#" id="paragraphAnchor">click me</a>
 <p>This is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a test</p>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>


  <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
  <script defer src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>
  <!-- end scripts-->


  <script> // Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID
    window._gaq = [['_setAccount','UAXXXXXXXX1'],['_trackPageview'],['_trackPageLoadTime']];
    Modernizr.load({
      load: ('https:' == location.protocol ? '//ssl' : '//www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'
    });
  </script>


  <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.attachEvent('onload',function(){CFInstall.check({mode:'overlay'})})</script>
  <![endif]-->

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE: ISSUE SOLVED**

It appears HTML 5 Boilerplate should have called the JavaScript with

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or at least that's how I got it working.

​

Comment: You should add an id or class to the p tag, else  $('p').hide(); will hide all the p tags in the page.

Comment: HTML5 Boilerplate loads the jQuery library itself, I think you are loading 2 jQuery libraries.

Comment: @kiranvj I'm just testing one at the moment. It's the only P tag I have. But thanks.

Comment: Do you have script-block (with the .ready-function) *before* or *after* the script-tag with the source to jquery lib?

Comment: @undefined I've updated my question with my entire HTML page.

Comment: `$(a#paragraphAnchor)` = `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`, the statement should use quotation marks as undefined pointed out in the answer: `$('a#paragraphAnchor')`.

Comment: Please don't put answers in your questions. There a specific place dedicated for answers. Put the solution that worked for you in an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery URL is missing the protocol. This line:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

should read

**http:**//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

**EDIT:** This is because the file is being loaded locally, so the assumed protocol `file` isn't going to be able to load any jquery libraries via HTTP(S).

This can be confirmed by checking the Console. Chrome reports:

```
Failed to load resource file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: why the downvote (i upvoted one) - this is correct.

Comment: @martinburch Is that now what I have already. In my question?

Comment: no you have // which should be http://

Comment: @m7o  check this http://jsfiddle.net/3LgYh/

Comment: @m7o: There is no difference, http:// and just // they execute the same way. Go here: http://jsfiddle.net/PypBz/, add or remove the http:// as required, the results are the same. Either way the p tag is removed.

Comment: Wow, I never realized that. Is that in the spec? Anyway, this is obviously not the answer then.

Comment: @MartinBurch It turns out you were right. Must just be a Sublime Text 2 thing.

Comment: +1 I see no reason why this is downvoted. To all downvoter plz free to add a comment after downvoting.

Comment: My apologies - i really wasn't aware of the "leaving out the protocol" thing, but i found the explanation - of course here on SA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Comment: So - no, this is not the correct answer, actually ;-)

Comment: @François it is not ok the remove the  "http://", just the "http:", to be exact.

Comment: @m7o: Yes you are correct, that was a typo in my comment, you do need the `//` off course as you said. Well spotted.

Comment: @m7o I have to say, now that I know it's not the correct answer, it feels odd to have this marked as correct when it should not be.

Comment: Waaaait just a darn second. This leaving off the http may be just fine when pages are served over http, but when accessed locally via the file protocol, that's not going to work. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <!-- CSS concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!-- end CSS-->

  <script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('p').hide();
       $('#paragraphAnchor').click(function() {
           $('p').show();
       });
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

jQuery is not loaded in your page, and note that you should use quotation marks for the selectors.

Comment: +1 as for noticing the missing quotation marks. I think that is all that was needed as that fixed it for me in the fiddle too. Without the quotation marks OP should get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`, with them his code should work I think.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Thanks, yes, by not using quotation marks, javascript interpreter tries to find a variable and throws an error. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need inside the `$(document).ready` function

```
$('#paragraphAnchor').click(function() {
  $('p').toggle();
});
```

Comment: That's making assumptions about what the op intended and doesn't answer the question

Comment: `toggle()` is different to `hide()`"The matched elements will be revealed or hidden immediately" -> http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Fair point! although if initial state was to be hidden then changing the markup would suffice

Comment: @JamesKyburz: There is no difference, http:// and just // they execute the same way. Go here: jsfiddle.net/PypBz (jquery is not included, only through script), add or remove the http:// as required, the results are the same. Either way the p tag is successfully removed with OPs original code. I think `undefined` might be on to something in the comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks @FrançoisWahl removed from answer

Comment: @JamesKyburz not sure if this was what you're talking about but I added 'http:' to the front of `<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`and it worked

Comment: Mmm @Michael must be a sublime thing then because it worked in textmate without http://, you live and learn

Answer (score 0):

Check this code it's work fine

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
{
      $("p").hide();
      $("a").click(function () {
      $("p").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="paragraphAnchor">click me</a>
 <p>This is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a testThis is  a test</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does Chrome allow users to view Jq on a local host? This say's not; http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-doesnt-work-on-localhost

Comment: That works! But what was wrong with my code?

Comment: importing JQuery Library 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
instead of 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are calling jquery code before it's loaded.

Add this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

before this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
  $('p').hide();
  $('a#paragraphAnchor').click(function()
  {
    $('p').show();
  });
});

  </script>
```

For example:

```
<head>
  ...

  <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
  $('p').hide();
  $('a#paragraphAnchor').click(function()
  {
    $('p').show();
  });
});

  </script>
</head>
...
```

Comment: The line for `window.jQuery || document.write...` is a standard way to inject your own version of the jquery library in-case the CDN is down. This will ensure jQuery is always loaded one way or another.