# Why is my toggle code not firing?

Tags: jquery, google-sites

Is there something obvious I'm missing below. I've got a simple html box gadget in a google site with minimal jquery to toggle a div off/on and it just doesn't seem to work. The code below works fine on an apache site page. Any tips ?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#check').click(function(){
        $('#feedback').toggle();
    });

</script>

<button id='check'>Check Answers</button>

<div id='feedback' style='display:none;'>
    <ul>
        <li>list 1</li>
        <li>list 2</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Put your codes inside `$(document).ready(function(){...})` handler.

Comment: You also need to put http: before //ajax.googleapis.com/...

Comment: @LeeTaylor - [No you don't](http://stackoverflow.com/q/550038/615754).

Comment: Google Site's HTML Box does not support .ready nor .load methods: https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en

Comment: I myself have also failed to use the .toggle() method. If I solve it I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your script is included before your elements then it runs before the elements have been parsed, which means `$("#check")` doesn't find any elements to bind the click handler to.

You need to either move the script block to *after* the element in question (just before the closing `</body>` tag is a common place to include scripts) or use a document ready handler which will wait to run your code until *after* all elements have been parsed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#check').click(function(){
        $('#feedback').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Google Site's HTML Box does not support .ready nor .load methods: support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en

Comment: @Luciano - OK then. Does it support including the script after the element (as per the first option I suggested)?

Comment: Yes @nnnnnn it should work. The documentation suggests including scripts at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get it to work with jquery.

Elliot Shafii helped me on the [google+ Google Sites community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/107454103091776894629) and the code below works:

```
<button id="infoToggle" value="toggle" onclick="document.getElementById('info').style.display=((document.getElementById('info').style.display=='block') ? 'none' : 'block')">Toggle</button>

<div id="info" style="display:block;">
TEST
</div>
```