# JQuery UI CSS style sheet not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Regardless of what I do, the CSS style sheet will not work. I've been trying for days with no luck. Even when I download a demo, some of the style does not work. See here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXdqd.png (tested in Chrome and Firefox)

So, I made this test code using Google's CDN in hopes that someone else can see what I'm doing wrong.

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text-html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>JQuery UI Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

    <!-- Accordion -->
    <h2 class="demoHeaders">Accordion</h2>
    <div id="accordion">
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
            <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
            <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <h2 class="demoHeaders">Button</h2>
    <button id="button">A button element</button>
    <form style="margin-top: 1em;">
        <div id="radioset">
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
        </div>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

This is what I get from the above code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiHQD.png

I would think this should be straightforward, but I must be doing something wrong. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what result are you expecting? The buttons in both images look the same to me. Are you expecting it to look different somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create any jQuery UI elements, you have to write a javascript code to create them.

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
        $("#button").button();
    });
</script>
```

Take a look at jQuery UI's documentation for more information:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Comment: Not sure why I couldn't find this in the JQuery documentation - thanks for the simple answer. The CSS is still not appearing properly, but at least some of the style is showing now.

Comment: You do not need the "http:" in the src. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)