# My jQuery isn't working

Tags: jquery

I am trying jQuery for the first time. This code was taken from W3schools. Here, if you click on the button you supposed to see 3 boxes. I haven't changed anything in the code except in the head I have changed the src. I am using Firefox.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
<button>Click to fade in boxes</button>
<br><br>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div><br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div><br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code seems to work just fine -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ua2a/14/).

Comment: It's working fine, I just tested!

Comment: What has the question got to do with google?

Comment: umm, i am using google api

Comment: @techfoobar He says the same code is not working with jQuery hosted on Google I guess...

Comment: @eddard.stark It's not Google API, it's jQuery library hosted on Google

Comment: Voting to close... as posted, code is valid & working.

Comment: @eddard.stark - The way you have included the google hosted version of jquery is correct. Your code seems to be working fine actually.

Comment: [Your code is working and valid](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ua2a/16/).  Until you can post an actual demo page showing otherwise, this question should be closed.

Comment: Just to clarify, `src="//` [is perfectly valid when page is hosted online](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http).  `src="//` is not necessarily valid when the page is hosted locally.  Although, unstated, the OP was apparently hosting the file locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your src = "http:// .... as it was not getting Jquery file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("#div1").fadeIn();
                $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
    <button>
        Click to fade in boxes</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="div1" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; display: none; background-color: red;">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="div2" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; display: none; background-color: green;">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="div3" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; display: none; background-color: blue;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still not working, should I download something?

Comment: I tested . just copy this code and create another html file and run it. i checked it in firefox as well. you have removed http:// from src url.

Comment: Leaving off `http:` is perfectly valid!

Comment: thanks @Moiz, it works when i use http:// in the src. why is that?

Comment: @Sparky672 : i would recommend you to try to local machine and create one file and check. if we put src =// then it keeps on loading , and if we remove that as well it will not load jquery.

Comment: does it have anything to do with my isp?

Comment: @eddard.stark : its because when you put // or remove that as well  the browser is searching that file locally that you dont have. if you want to remove that then download a copy of that and then call that directly

Comment: @eddard.stark : no not with isp. its just that your browser is not getting the Jquery Lib of which you are calling the Functions.

Comment: Of course you need `http://` when the OP is using file _locally_!  Where did he state that he was using it locally?  And where do you explain that was your theory?

Comment: @Sparky672: in the code example given by eddard it is <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> So i just told to write src="http://"

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/550073/594235

Comment: No, he did not state he was using the code example _locally_.

Comment: @Sparky672:if we dont put http then the browser understands that its a local file. and search locally.

Comment: You are incorrect.  Again, read this question & answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20842/discussion-between-moiz-and-sparky672)

Comment: If you're still not convinced, see `src="//ajax.googleapis.com...` in this _working_ _online_ example:  http://jsfiddle.net/2Ua2a/14/

Comment: @Sparky672:I know it works in jsfiddle.I dont know what mechanism jsfiddle is using so i would suggest you to create one html file on your desktop, put this code and try to run.

Comment: There is no trickery in jsFiddle. I know `src="//` will not work on desktop!  However, `src="//` **WILL** work _online_.  Upload file yourself if you still refuse to believe [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/550073/594235) and [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ua2a/14/).

Comment: @Sparky672:I know that will work on servers. the Owner of the question is running that thing on desktop. that is the only reason he put on this query. anywayz nice conversation :)

Comment: And he **never** stated he was running it off his desktop which was what I said ten comments ago, just before you claimed it was due to "unknown" jsFiddle mechanism.  Nor did your answer explain this critical technical distinction.

Comment: Yes true, when the code didnt worked, i assumed that he is running that on local machine.

Comment: Lucky, most other people assume _web page_ code is _online_ someplace.

Comment: i assumed coz the code was correct. and found only one issue with that.