# document.createElement('script') vs <script src="">

Tags: javascript, html

Why is it that services like Google and Facebook use `document.createElement('script')` instead of just `<script>`?

The Google Analytics snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

could be written as just:

```
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and Facebook's like button:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

could be simplified as just:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxx"></script>
```

I know there's some playing safe in them, but other than that I don't see why we shouldn't use the HTML5 ones?

Comment: The first one (google) no, it can't the url is different for ssl. And this syntax will only work with javascript, so there won't be a  resource request in case the client has no js or it is deactivated.

Comment: `//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js` can be used via `http` and `https` and if JavaScript is disabled nothing in `<script>` will be run, so no difference.

Comment: @axel.michel standards say script tag should be ignored when there is no js support available

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `<script src=...>` blocks the browser while `document.createElement('script')` loads the JavaScript asynchronously; this is the primary reason.

---

The `<script src=...>` tag blocks browser from displaying rest of the page until the script is loaded and executed. This ensures that scripts are executed in correct order and any `document.write()` in that script work as expected. However this creates a laggy browsing experience for the user.

When the script is loaded asynchronously, the browser can download the script without blocking the page display. This improves the browsing experience dramatically.

To load the scripts asynchronously one can use HTML markup:

```
<script src="..." async defer></script>
```

The [**`async`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html#script.attrs.async) attribute was introduced in HTML5 while the [**`defer`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html#script.attrs.defer) attribute can be added as a fallback for older versions of IE. [This document describes how async and defer attribute work](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async).

Alternately, one can use JavaScript to build a script tag:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "...";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

JavaScript generated script tags work in most browsers even if they do not understand the `async` attribute or `.async = true` property.

---

About schemeless URIs (`//example.com/script.js`): schemeless URIs seem to work almost everywhere ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/550038/87015)).

About the Google Analytics example: both old and new code use JavaScript to detect the protocol then load `http://www.` or `https://ssl.` which is not possible via HTML markup.

Comment: excellent, so provided I only care about users riding recent browsers and if my site is only available via HTTP the best approach would be `<script src="http://example.com/lib.js" async="async" defer="defer"></script>` and perhaps even put it in the bottom of the page.

Comment: @webjay Also note the facebook script contains additional logic: it checks it the script was already added to the page, and don't add it again if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, doesn't even have to be on the bottom!

Comment: I don't see a reason why you would add defer to a script tag at the end of the document. See here my reason's for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065664/is-google-using-defer-the-wrong-way

Comment: @MaartenBruins a synchronous script placed at the end could still take seconds to download (or minutes or not download at all) and delay the dom loaded event in the mean time.

Comment: @SalmanA I know, but if the script tag is at the end of the document, then it has only influence on "</body></html>" and those tags have no influence on what you will see on the screen (rendering). So in practise is has no effect on that. And usually with async, the execution will start usually a little bit later, if you compare it with just sync. So that would be a reason to not use async, but sync(if you would have 1 script tag at the end of the document).

Comment: @MaartenBruins I see your point but still... what if there are other scripts on the page that run on document ready? Their functionality will be blocked until that script is loaded.

Comment: @SalmanA That's why i wrote "if you would have 1 script tag". Decisions are just depending on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Salman A's excellent point about deferred loading this technique is used when the static solution won't work.

- I've seen it used when caching is an issue (a unique time based hash is added to the URL)
- In the case of the google link shown above SSL can be dynamically turned on.
- In the facebook code it checks if the script already exists (this can avoid bugs where the same script is loaded twice).

There can be other reasons too.  All of them have to do with needing a dynamic solution.

Comment: I can't see a reason for the facebook code - if you will read my and you will

Comment: @ParvSharma - I didn't see a reason for the facebook code in your answer, but Salman A did give a compelling reason.

Comment: this way websites can check whether the same script is present and then choose not to download it again as being done in facebooks example

Answer (score 0):

yes that can be written in a script tag but the examples you have quoted are the ones where the website is providing user with some code block which they are required to copy paste in their websites
so injecting is better because this way the website like google and facebook
1.as you can see in the googles example you have provided it dynamically detectes http OR https
2. this way websites can check wethther the same script is present and then choose not to download it again as being done in facebooks example
3. have more control over what is being injected. as the script that is being injected can be changed dynamically without users being required to change the url of the script being injected and this is necessary as many browsers just keep the scripts in cache
4.this way these websites keep their codes sort and less prone to user interference

Comment: but other than that they are not faster?

Comment: no they are not.. infact they are slower as the script that is being using to dynamically inject is also taking its space