# Html5 async attribute vs js async property

Tags: javascript, html

what is the difference between  Html5 async attribute vs js async property.

```
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" async>
```

and

```
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
    ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

are they interchangeable

Comment: `(function() {...});` is on `<head>...</head>` or in on js file?

Comment: I believe that within the head tag the effect is the same. Personally I prefer `<script>` with `<head>`, perhaps the reason google-Analitics is only detect https or http, like @SalmanA said).

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not interchangeable.

Script tag with async attribute executes at the first opportunity after it is downloaded and before `window.onload` event. So you dont know **when** that script executes.
On the other hand, script loaded within a javascript file can execute whenever you want (after or before `window.onload` event).

Some links: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script.

**Edit:**
`ga.async = true;` as said in Salman A. answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14666847/2044286) is omitted by the parser.

Comment: So what happens if you set `s.async = false`?

Comment: Nothing. It has no effect (for small files, at least).

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript is creating the HTML element you are talking about. In JavaScript, the property itself has no meaning, in this case its just a property with the value `true`.

When the browser reads the HTML, the value gets a meaning.