# does it matter if you use an actual .js file when pulling it in as source from one domain to another

Tags: javascript, src

Sort of an odd question but I cannot find anything on Google about it. When pulling in a .js file, like in the below code ( Facebook Dev ):

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src =     "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=111111";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

What is he js.src was something like //connect.facebook.net/en/sdk and on that page was all of the javascript code as just plain text. Putting this between the script tags would make it act as javascript. I have done a few tests and it seems to work fine but I'm convinced I am missing something.

So in a nutshell, is this ok / secure / stable?

Comment: Thank you both for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine. Simply this add more layers, like avoiding doubleinserting the same script.

This simply creates a DOM element like this:

```
<script id="facebook-jssdk" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=111111" />
```

Step by step:

```
(function(d, s, id) { // function with 3 arguments
  // Because of the call below, the arguments are:
  // d = document
  // s = "script"
  // id = "facebook-jssdk"
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; // Gets all elements of type "script"
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return; // Checks if any of the existent elements have the id "facebook-jssdk", to not doubleinsert
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; // Creates an element of type "script" and sets the id
  js.src =     "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=111111"; // Sets the source
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); // Inserts the script
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); // calls the function above with 3 parameters
```

So yes, it will actually think that the file is a javascript one, as it is loaded the same way as usually with other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

2 things. First, your source file is in fact a js file (connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js) with some data afterwards. I tried opening the full and short url and they appear to be the same source file so it shouldn't matter if you just used connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js.

Second, you can have an opening script tag with type="text/javascript"
or you can declare it within the script tag itself using the document.createElement('script') way, as you did with (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk').

Either way is ok, but there is a great post that explains the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666658/document-createelementscript-vs-script-src)

Also, you did it the way the [facebook SDK instructions recommend](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart), so I am sure it's secure. ;-)