# CSP: Why is document.createElement("script") good and document.write("<script ...") bad?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I'm just a bit confused. I've been going through a [presentation slide deck on Content Security Policies](https://2017.appsec.eu/presos/Developer/So%20we%20broke%20all%20CSPs...%20You%20won%27t%20guess%20what%20happened%20next!%20-%20Michele%20Spagnuolo%20and%20Lukas%20Weichselbaum%20-%20OWASP_AppSec-Eu_2017.pdf). On slide 10, when discussing the `'strict-dynamic'` directive, three examples are given: one good, two bad:

```
// good
<script nonce="r4nd0m">
 var s = document.createElement("script");
 s.src = "//example.com/bar.js";
 document.body.appendChild(s);
</script> 

// bad
<script nonce="r4nd0m">
 var s = "<script src=//example.com/bar.js></script>";
 document.write(s);
 // -OR-
 document.body.innerHTML = s;
</script>
```

Google also advises to make similar changes on their [CSP page](https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/adopting-csp.html) ("Refactor calls to JS APIs incompatible with CSP").
I understand that the good example loads async while the bad one doesn't ([unless `async defer` is added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14666847/2018047)). But...

If I wanted to load an evil script, wouldn't both ways get me there?

Is the issue that the "bad" way doesn't propagate the nonce (automatically)? Or is it about the "bad" way being a bit [like a call to eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations) in that you can do pretty much anything with it (although, in HTML 5, a [script wouldn't execute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations) unless attached to an event handler, apparently)? Is the assumption that the "bad" way [likely uses parser-inserted user input](https://youtu.be/YBBqtrJmMRc?t=445) and that's why it's bad (that's what I got from the presentation video I found later)?

Why is one call permissible while the other isn't (when, in the example given, they seem to achieve the same thing - loading an external script)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: @Teemu I saw that, but just by scrolling through, I couldn't really see any reason why it would be an issue in the context of CSP, as opposed to `document.createElement('script')`...?

Comment: Probably because bad practices are bad practices nevertheless the context ..?

Comment: CSP is a security feature. These aren't usually used to stop people from implementing bad practices, unless they also pose a security issue? (Sonar/Lint is for stopping bad practices, right?)