# Is //sub.sitename.com/thing/ standard?

Tags: html, browser, standards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src=“http://…”>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

I just saw `//sub.sitename.com/thing/` in a url. Is this standard? I would assume it keeps the scheme (http vs https) when going to the other site but I don't know. Is this standard? or a sin in the html world?

Comment: Wait, are you saying that there are websites out there that don't have `http`/`https` in their URL's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, this is standardized by [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) § 4.2:

> A relative reference takes advantage of the hierarchical syntax
>      (Section 1.2.3) to express a URI reference relative to the name space
>      of another hierarchical URI.
>
> [...]
>
> A relative reference that begins with two slash characters is termed
>      a network-path reference; such references are rarely used.