# Jquery not working with any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is like this. But it is not working on any browser. this code has been copy-pasted from w3scools. Same is the condition with my other codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     $("p").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I hope you have a closing `</html>` tag.

Comment: I don't see any problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8CcdP/

Comment: "it is not working" That is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to your jQuery script is not working. Replace it with:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Instead.

It wasn't working for me with the old link, but after replacing it with the other link it worked just fine.

(I'm assuming you noticed the missing `</html>`.)

Comment: `w3fools.com` - The outdated website that tells w3schools to wikify their content, while not wikifying their own website. Oh the irony.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792954/jquery-load-not-working-on-phonegap

@DOORKNOB can you plz help me wid dis?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this will work, but try adding `http:` to the beginning of your link reference. Additionally, as others have pointed out, close your `<html>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     $("p").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Another thing I would suggest, is using jQuery's CDN for jQuery hosting. The URL's a lot shorter, and it gets you the latest version without having to define the version:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, I see you're using version 1.8.3, which could be for a specific reason, so just add the version you want after `jquery` in the url. `jquery-1.8.3.min.js`.

Comment: This answer still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Doorknob Oh, but I see you edited your answer to say the same thing I said after I posted my answer. Hmm....

Comment: No, it doesn't say the same thing. I edited it because I copy/pasted his code and found that it didn't work with the link. I changed it to the jQuery download page.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, he's using 1.8.3 which could be for good reason. You may want to note that in your answer.

Comment: @ModernDesigner can you plz help me wid dis?

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually does work (even without the missing html closing tag :-P) but only if it is run from a server. It is all to do with the URI for the jQuery file.

If you run the file locally, the browser guesses that it should download the file using the file protocol, so:

```
file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
```

If you open up your browser's developer tools (by pressing the F12 key usually), it should show you an error saying the browser couldn't load the jQuery file from a file:// URL. If you put http (or https) as the protocol, it knows where to get jQuery from and everything works.

Interestingly if you run the file on a server (which I guess is what w3schools intended) then the browser guesses it should be the http or https protocols and it finds the jQuery file.

If you want to experiment running a webserver without putting in much effort, Python (because it is awesome) lets you run a web server with just one command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

It runs the server on:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

and serves the files from the directory where you run it. This url has a little more detail about it: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python

I wasn't aware of the server requirement (thanks for the question!) and I found this in my travels which I thought was interesting. It talks about how the missing protocol is valid html [StackOverflow: Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)