# jquery.load() not working on phonegap

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cordova

I am developing buyers guide app with phonegap. where i am trying to fetch some info from server using jquery. but when i run following code with phonegap its not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $('#div1').load('http://localhost/MySample.php');
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Click to get information</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the device you're building this on have a webserver?

Comment: yes.. It has apache n php instald

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript error console?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CORS enabled on the server?

PhoneGap loads the index.html from the local filesystem and the same origin policy prevents ajax calls to different domains, such as localhost.

Comment: No. .i dont hav cors enbld on ma servr

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on simulator or on a device?

You can't use localhost on a device because localhost is the device, you have to use the server local IP instead

And you have to whitelist the IP too (or use *, it whitelist all the IPs) 
[whitelist guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html)

Comment: M using it on simulator. . 
Then hw cn I do it widout usin localhost?

Comment: If you are using the simulator, then localhost should work, so it has to be the whitelist problem. Look at the link I posted with the whitelist guide