# Simple jQuery Will Not Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, accordion, squarespace

I'm trying to re-learn HTML/CSS/JavaScript and coming across an issue with a site I'm building. I'm on Squarespace and trying to implement jQuery. I have simple code and it will not work. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

This is in my "Page Header Code Injection"

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And this is in my actual page:

```
<div id="accordion">

<h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Blah
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Secion 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p> lalala
    </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Do I need to declare "text/javascript"? I've tried adding "https", declaring it HTML5, etc...

Please help! I've searched around.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running this on a webserver, or from a folder on your computer.

Comment: Which script is not working?

Comment: What do you expect it to do? All you are doing is including jQuery, you're not actually doing anything with it.

Comment: All of it is not working. I was lead to believe that I could run it from the google's site?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you seeing any error messages, strange behavior, or other clues?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, when I load the page, the accordion style is not working. I'm doing a simple tutorial that has squarespace and jquery... and beginning to believe the tutorial might be wrong.

Comment: Did you ever call `$('#accordian').accordian()`?

Comment: @Kelsey: Do you have a link to that tutorial?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help... I'm currently attempting now. 

Link: [link]https://altankhendup.com/blog/2013/3/19/customizing-squarespace-6-adding-more-to-your-site[/link]

Comment: That should be `$('#accordion').accordion()`

Comment: THANK YOU TO EVERYONE!! It finally worked. You all rock my world. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to actually use the accordion widget from jQuery UI? In that case you need to actually run some code to tell jQuery that you want to do that.

*After* your tags importing the two scripts, add this:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
     $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
 });
</script>
```

This tells jQuery to find the tag with the id `accordion` and run the function `.accordion()` on it, which in jQuery UI turns it into the accordion widget.

Also note, the protocol less URLs is designed so you can switch between `http:` and `https` without having to change your code. Unfortunately, it won't work if you are running your page from the file system (`file:`) because it will then try to load the scripts from your local hard drive. Explicitly add `http:` at the beginning of the URL if you are running locally.

Comment: Thank you, but sadly, none of the suggestions are working. I think it's how Squarespace renders it's code. I'm running through their website and not through anything else.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using from **local**, then it would look for `file://` which doesn't exists. Use this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>$(function() {$( "#accordion" ).accordion();});</script> <!-- To call accordion-->
```

**Edit**: Using `//`, have a look at error in js console:
[image]

Comment: `src="//` **doesn't** resolve to `file://`. it will resolve to `http://` or `https://`. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Comment: It sure does, if being accessed **locally**. Edited my answer, have a look.

Comment: Right, but you edited your answer. Plus, OP says "I'm on [Squarespace](http://new.squarespace.com/) and trying to implement jQuery.", which means *not* local.

Comment: I said *if you are using from local...*. Plus in edit I only added the pic and made "local" bold ;)

Comment: Thank you! I'm receiving an error still on my end, but I think it is how Squarespace loads its stuff. Thanks, though!! I'm still troubleshooting this tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the jQuery UI accordion, you need to set it up:

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
 </script>
```

Also, make sure your HTML markup matches what is expected by the accordion plugin:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem</p>
    </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lastly, make sure you're also including the CSS for jQuery UI:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />`

> See this link: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Thank you, I've attempted everything and I'm thinking it is because of the way Squarespace loads things.

Answer (score 2):

To use the accordion UI widget, you need to instantiate it like this:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
```

after the external sources are loaded.

This is found in the documentation: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Click "View Source" link.

Comment: Thank you! Honestly, I think it's squarespace and how they render their site. I will keep trying. Thank you, again.