# Client-side website reachability test

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a Facebook application which runs through the apps.facebook.com system. This question is not about Facebook apps specifically (so don't stop reading if you are not familiar with these) but you'll see why this is important shortly.

Whenever a user wishes to use the app, they will go firstly to a standard website (with a more memorable address, let's use the example xyz.com) which will then automatically redirect to the Facebook application. However, there are two possible redirection destinations:

1. To the standard Facebook application page (e.g. apps.facebook.com/xyz). This should occur if the client can reach that page. Importantly, a reason that the client may not be able to reach this page is if they are on a network running a content filter (e.g. schools, universities, some workplaces) which blocks Facebook.
2. If the client cannot reach the Facebook application page they should be redirected to another page on the main website (e.g. xyz.com/nofacebook_login.html).

As you can see, the redirection decision needs to be based upon whether the **client** can reach the Facebook application page, or not. Therefore, the testing will need to occur on the client-side (presumably) using Javascript, jQuery, or similar. However, I am unsure how to go about this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How granular is that filter? Can we assume if one thing is blocked, then everything is blocked on that domain?

Comment: Most web filters are domain-based (rather than page based) so you can assume that if apps.facebook.com is blocked then everything on that (sub)domain is blocked.

Comment: now I just need to find something that I can test on that domain. If I just XHR there, I'll hit a same-origin barrier

Comment: I would like to assume that if `apps.facebook.com/*` is blocked, then `**.facebook.com/*` is blocked as well. May I?

Comment: Yes, that's a fair assumption (as the user needs to be able to use other resources of Facebook to effectively use the app). By the way, PHP is perfectly fine if needed, but no good for pure reachability testing since that will be server-side.

Comment: This might help if you can get the target server to respond http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: @Spokey if you can distinguish same-origin-blocked requests from truly inaccessible requests (or facebook sends CORS headers - I'll test), the rest is easy.

Comment: It seems that Facebook serves all static content from the domain `bcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net`. It's hard to imagine _this_ domain will be blocked together with `apps.facebook.com`.

Comment: Yeah, Akamai is a CDN so it's unlikely that would be blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious solution (just send an AJAX request to the remote domain and see what is the response)  doesn't work due to the same-origin policy.

You could ask Facebook to implement the [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) protocol. If they agree, the rest is easier. If not, however, `$.ajax` - or the native `XmlHttpRequest` - won't do.

However, while the XHRs are subject to the same-origin policy, other ways to send an HTTP request are not: You can create an image with the `src` of some image on `apps.facebook.com`, and see if it loads. The problem here is that facebook serves most of its content from `akamaihd.net`, which is unlikely to be co-blocked with `apps.facebook.com`. I did, however, find *one* image served from `apps.facebook.com`: 
http://apps.facebook.com/images/spacer.gif (http://facebook.com/images/spacer.gif also exists). @RobW also pointed me to the favicon (http://apps.facebook.com/favicon.ico)

To test if an image can be loaded:

1. create a new `img` element
2. add a `load` listener and an `error` listener to it, that will perform the redirect
3. set the `img` `src`
4. adding the image to the document should not be neccessary, but I haven't tested everywhere.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.onload = function(){location.href = "http://apps.facebook.com/xyz"};
img.onerror = function(){location.href = "http://xyz.com/nofacebook_login.html"};
img.src = "//apps.facebook.com/favicon.ico"; //thanks @RobW
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

---

Note: nowhere does Facebook guarantee either image will always exist. While there seems to be a decent chance it will stay, it may disappear eventually. If this happens, everyone will appear blocked (you may want to check the error code, but I don't know what the blockers return). If it happens, please notify me or update this answer with a new working image.

Comment: `(location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + "//apps.facebook.com/favicon.ico"` would be better, because it uses the right protocol, and a favicon is not likely to go away.

Comment: _“You could ask Facebook to implement […]”_ – you are a very funny man.

Comment: @RobW: You can just use `//apps.facebook.com/` without specifying the protocol explicitly – then browser will then use the protocol he used to load the main document from automatically.

Comment: @CBroe Unless you're using a non-http scheme such as `file:`.

Comment: @RobW updated, thanks. Concerning `//`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Comment: @RobW you are right about `file:`. I don't expect to encounter that protocol, however.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone (especially Jan). This solution looks good.