# Why using "src=//" instead of "src=http://"

Tags: html, src

I had never noticed that before, but if you go to the [Google libraries pages](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#troubleshooting), all the HTML is coded with the `src=//`expression, i.e. for Jquery :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But if you go to the [Jquery page](http://jquery.com/download/), they told to us to embed the code with an `src=http://`
like

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

I don't really get what the difference between the two of them?

What's the pros & cons of these use?

### EDIT :

Ok, i uderstand the meaning of this, the first one allows you to keep the same protocol for loading the lib, `http` or `https`. But is that it? There is no speed/security/deeper reasons for that ?

Seems weird to me, the `src=http://`works everywhere, the first one don't works on a local file, so why should i use the `src=//`expression ?

Comment: Have a look here, this explains everything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Comment: This makes the src attribute scheme agnostic.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Comment: If you do not load external resources from a protocol relative URI, you might see a warning in an `https` page, as it loads "non-secure" http content.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu this relative expr/ avoid the certificate verification ?

Comment: I just made an edit to the first question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a *protocol-relative* URI - if it appears in an http page it'll be treated as `http://` but if it appears in an https page it'll be treated as `https://`.

If a page loaded over https includes other resources that are loaded over http then browsers will present a warning or may even consider the page as a whole to be "insecure". In order to ensure that the user doesn't get a "broken padlock" all images, JS and CSS files must also be https (not necessarily loaded from the same server or protected by the same certificate, but they must all be https connections that the browser knows to trust).

An http page loading https resources is less of an issue, but since you don't really gain anything in terms of the user experience by doing this, you might as well just load the resources via http too.

Comment: Is that it? There is no security/speed/loading reasons for that? Seems weird because `src=http://`works everywhere every time, the `src=//`don't works locally...

Comment: @x_vi_r: Since it’s a protocol-relative URI, `//` locally will be equivalent to `file://`. And yes, it’s a matter of security, and speed to a lesser extent (HTTPS isn’t quite as fast as plain HTTP, though the difference isn’t usually huge now). I think IE (8-?) had a bug where protocol-relative URIs would be requested twice, though, so don’t rely on it to be necessarily a performance improvement or anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is used to use the same protocol as the source page.

If the page is loaded used http protocol then the library files will be loaded using http, if https is used to load the page then the library also will use the same protocol