# LinkedIn Member Profile Plugin

Tags: html, css, linkedin-api

I'm attempting to use LinkedIn's Membership Profile Plugin found here:

```
http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile-plugin-generator
```

However, every time I paste the code generated into my HTML document, nothing seems so show up. Forgive my ignorance if I'm missing something, I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS. After doing some searching I've seen a lot of talk about their API. Do I need an API key to get this to work? Or am I just missing something in my code?

Here is an example of the code I'm attempting to use:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="(Profile URL)" data-format="inline"></script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try adding `http` in front of your script src

Comment: @tymeJV It's not necessary.

Comment: @WooCaSh -- If this is being hosted from the local machine it may add `file` in front of it..it wont find the lib at `file://..`

Comment: @tymeJV http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Comment: Are you test it on any web server or only on localhost without any server?

Comment: Currently testing on a localHost without any server. I tried adding http: before the source giving me a line like this(without the space):

"<script src="http: //platform.linkedin.com/in.js"..."

However, it did not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely has to do with the fact that you are accessing it through `file://C:\ ... \mypage.html` instead of hosting it on a server like `http://myserver.com/mypage.html`.

You can see the error in Chrome if you press F12 for Developer Tools, under Console. It is hard to find the original reason, because all of it is run in those scripts.

But the scripts work, and you can see it running if you just paste it in somewhere like [W3Schools TryIt page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_lib_jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try with your "linkedin short url". For Example: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/xy":

You can customize your public profile URL when you edit your public profile. Custom public profile URLs are available on a first come, first served basis.

```
1.Move your cursor over Profile at the top of your homepage and select Edit Profile.
2.Click the URL link under your profile photo. It will be an address like www.linkedin.com/in/yourname
3.Under the Your public profile URL section on the right, click the Edit icon next to your URL.
4.Type the last part of your new custom URL in the text box.
5.Click Save.
```