# How do I have a different image load on each page refresh?

Tags: jquery, image, page-refresh

I am trying to have a different image load with each page refresh. I have tried this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body> <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-source"></script> <script>$(document).load( ... )</script><script type="text/javascript">(function($){

$.randomImage = {
    defaults: {

        //you can change these defaults to your own preferences.
        path: 'http://mysite.com/images/', //change this to the path of your images
        myImages: ['Testimonial1.png', 'Testimonial2.png', 'Testimonial3.png', 'Testimonial4.png', 'Testimonial5.png' ] //put image names in this bracket. ex: 'harold.jpg', 'maude.jpg', 'etc'

    }           
}

$.fn.extend({
        randomImage:function(config) {

            var config = $.extend({}, $.randomImage.defaults, config); 

             return this.each(function() {

                    var imageNames = config.myImages;

                    //get size of array, randomize a number from this
                    // use this number as the array index

                    var imageNamesSize = imageNames.length;

                    var lotteryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*imageNamesSize);

                    var winnerImage = imageNames[lotteryNumber];

                    var fullPath = config.path + winnerImage;


                    //put this image into DOM at class of randomImage
                    // alt tag will be image filename.
                    $(this).attr( {
                                    src: fullPath,
                                    alt: winnerImage
                                });

            }); 
        }   
});

}(jQuery));</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am a jQuery and JavaScript newb, and it's not working for me. I'm definitely doing something wrong, but I don't know where to begin with jQuery. I'm pretty sure it's a syntax error. Could anyone help me out?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some back and forth, but here is the code, this should work with no problems:

https://gist.github.com/AstDerek/5841966

---

Original answer

Your code works http://jsfiddle.net/AstDerek/AC6tu/

If you still have problems, try checking jQuery is loaded. The browser may complain if the call to the anonymous function is made outside of the first match of parenthesis:

Wrong:

```
})(jQuery);
```

Right:

```
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Then I think my problem stems from the idea that I have no idea how to  fit the code into my html page. This is the actual code that I have around that other code. Maybe I just don't have the right things in the right places. Do I need to say <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"> before the code above and </script> at the end? I'm not sure how to do it in the first place. I checked moving the ) like you said, and it didn't work with what I have. Will it still work if the code library link is not in the header?

Comment: The `src` attribute is interpreted as a relative path: `http://yoursite.com/ajax.googleapis.com/etc`. Just add `https://` or `//` at the start of the path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Comment: Thanks Ast Derek! That answers my question about the // in front of the src I am now using. I am now using <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">, but it is still not loading my images. I'm using it on a new clear html page that I just created. The images are in an image folder and nothing else. I don't know what I could be doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Two things: script tags with `src` attr will only load scripts from the path give, to define inline js you need another script tag pair with no `src`: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-source"></script> <script>$(document).load( ... )</script>` You also need to actually call the plugin, add an `img` tag and run `$('img').randomImage();` somewhere after the tag has loaded.

Comment: Thanks Ask Derek. I have updated my code above to show what I now have. If I was supposed to put anything in the load(...), I don't know what it is. And I have no idea how to add an img tag and run $('img').randomImage();    Very new to jquery and JavaScript. Thank you!

Comment: It was merely descriptive: `(function($){}(jQuery))` is a wrapper function, you pass `jQuery` as an argument and the function aliases `jQuery` as `$`. `$(document).ready(function(){})` registers the function to be executed when the `document` is "ready". I added a new link at the question: https://gist.github.com/AstDerek/5841966

Comment: Oh my gosh Ast Derek you fixed it! It's working now! I'm a newb at js but I'm learning! This is great. You're a life-saver. I appreciate your help. Thanks!!!!

Comment: I hate to bother you again, but when I put this same code into a WordPress page it doesn't work well. I put it into my theme and it will only output in the logo div at the top of the page, even if the div is in the footer (and is not the logo). It will not display anywhere else on the page, but displays well in a sole html or php test page on the same server. Do you know what the problem could be? Is there a way to show the images rotating in a WordPress page? I believe it'd have to be in a <div>. Thank you so much!!!!!!!

Comment: Adding a slider to WP is somewhat different, you might need to ask a new question. Debugging the theme is also complicated as no one but you knows the code you are editing.

Comment: Yeah good point. With lots of searching I found this: http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/php_random_image_rotation.html and it is working well. So I am going to use it for now, but thank you for helping me learn so much jquery!!!