# Grunt cdnify creates broken AngularJS CDN link

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I use Yeoman/Grunt with the Angular generator, and after running `grunt build`, the AngularJS reference in my **dist/index.html** looks like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

So, `http:` is missing, which I manually have to change to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

In the **original index.html**, the reference looks like this:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Is this a config error in my `Gruntfile.js`?

Comment: `http:` is not required in script src  for many CDN's. Here's another example  http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: // is just fine. take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Comment: Well my app fails until I add `http:`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*//* simply represents "use the protocol of the current file"

So if your index.html uses http, the CDN will be fetched using http. Same with https.

I'm guessing you are testing locally and the browser uses the file: protocol. Should work once you use a server.

Comment: Spot on! I was running local `file://`.