# how to determine if page is using http or https in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a 'footer' shared partial view I have third party code that should use `http://` or `https://` to call their third party program depending on if the page is using `http` or `https`. How can I determine that in the partial view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Request.IsSecureConnection` in your view (if using Razor) should tell you if the connection is over SSL or not. Keep in mind that this won't work if IIS is not actually doing the SSL negotiation.

If the link is just for client-side consumption in HTML/JavaScript *and* differs only by the scheme you can use the `//example.com/resource.js` URL style and it will copy the current scheme. See [this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)