# Why isn't my Jquery Validate working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have done some online research and can not find a solution. I am using the Jquery Validator plug in to validate my log in and registration forms. I have coded my registration form and it works exactly as it should. However I coded my log in the same exact way and it does not work. When I have blank fields, no message is displayed and the form is allowed to be submitted.

Sign-in.php

```
<html>
<head>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../skin/frontend/css/styles.css" media="all"> 
 <?php include('../js/jquery.js'); ?>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/validator.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/sign-in.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header"><?php include('../app/views/frontend/header.php'); ?></div>
        <div class="body-container">
                Sign in <br>
                <form method="post" action="../account/signin/sign-in.php" id="signin"> 
                <input type ='text'placeholder='Username' name="usernamesignin" id="usernamesignin" ><br>
                <br>
                <input type='text' onfocus="this.type='password'" placeholder='Password' name="passwordsignin" id="passwordsignin"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Log In">
                </form>
                </div>
    </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Sign-in.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#signin").validate({
  rules: {
     usernamesignin: {
        required: true
           },
           passwordsignin:{
         required: true,
         minlength:6
         }
            },
           messages: {
                 username: {
        required: "Please Enter A Username"
           }
  }
     });
     });
```

Am I missing something? This should be pretty simple.

Also I notice in my console.log that my registration page throws no errors, however my signin page shows:  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined"

Not sure if that is the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know if that is a typo in your question but you are missing space between your form action and form id in your html

Comment: Why are you including jQuery twice?

Comment: That is a good question.. Not sure why I am including twice lol

Comment: Wow!! Thank you @b.enoit.be !! It was a simple typo throwing this error! lol Fixed it!

Comment: @Brandon no offense please, but if you can, vote to close your question since a typo is the kind of bug very unlikly to help someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Type in form action and form id.. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I've got your validation by doing the following:

1. Remove the line `"<?php include('../js/jquery.js'); ?>"`. You shouldn't have two references to jQuery
2. Edit the following line to be `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`. You are missing the protocol `https:`

As per the this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http), you should be able to define a URI without a protocol, but in this instance, when linking to the code.jquery.com CDN, it does not work.