# Is it possible to have an absolute href attribute with no scheme?

Tags: python, html, tags, uri, url-scheme

I'm trying to find a way to test whether a URL is absolute or relative in Python. In the href attribute of an HTML tag, is the lack of a scheme (e.g. http, ftp, etc.) sufficient to mark a URL as relative, or is it possible to have an absolute URL as a href attribute without explicitly specifying the scheme (e.g. 'www.google.com')? I'm getting the scheme by using `urlparse.urlparse('some url').scheme`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't include the URI scheme (`http://`, `https://`, `//`, etc) then the browser will assume it to be a relative URL.

You should be aware of scheme-relative URLs like `//www.google.com` for your script.  In short your should look for a double forward slash `//` to figure out whether or not a URL will be treated as relative or not.

Answer (score 1):

As per [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

```
<a href="//example.com/page.html">Link</a>
```

Source, and more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/550073/2454476

And in python:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
>>> from urlparse import urlparse;
>>> urlparse('//example.com/page.html');
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='example.com', path='/page.html', params='', query='', fragment='')
```