# How to embed DailyMotion video on local html page?

Tags: html, video, embed, dailymotion-api

I'm looking on how to embed a DailyMotion video on local html page, it works on server, but not on local.

in my web application, I'm embedding both of DailyMotion and Youtube videos on this webapp , youtube videos are working but not DailyMotion videos

I'm using simple Iframe embed method :

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2p99yn" ></iframe>
```

Comment: I think the protocol is missing in *src*. Could you try with http://-url ?

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the protocol to the source url: in your iframe, you have `src="//www` and you need to replace it by `src="http://www` for it to work in local