# Why the protocol is not present in dojo CDN import code

Tags: javascript, dojo

I started learning Dojo and came across how to include Dojo using CDN by below code which is defined in [Dojo Tutorial][1]

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true">
```

Here why they have missed `http`? Is that intentional, my program is not working unless I add `http` in my code. I was trying on Mozilla browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exclusion of protocol is intentional - the script will load using the protocol that the page was loaded with. [More details can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Quick question - are you loading up your HTML file locally or from a server?

Comment: I was loading it locally so I got the issue, now I tried to access it from a server and it worked. Thanks a lot for clarification :)