# JQuery table cell sorting by drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html-table, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I am not very familiar about jQuery table cell sorting using drag/drop capabilities. I have tried using jquery plugin but it only sort the whole `tr` but I am not sure how to do in following situation and limitations.

Situation:

Implement a table with drag & drop capability for the red regions with the following limitations:

Limitations:

- The Brand cannot be dragged and dropped at all.
- The Main Category cannot be dragged and dropped beyond its parent Brand.
- The Sub Category cannot be dragged and dropped beyond its Main Category.
- The Product cannot be dragged and dropped beyond its parent Sub Category.

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

[image: Img3]

I have added my work in Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/XkMGWwgh50iz9c2e4W4W?p=preview

If you see in Plunkr above it's not able to sort as per above images example.

Need help and it's highly appreciable.

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391691/drag-and-drop-using-jqueryui-not-working it will help

Comment: @Pekka I have checked the question above somehow mine situation is different from above I have added my example at plunkr above and also here: http://plnkr.co/edit/XkMGWwgh50iz9c2e4W4W?p=preview
Please look if you can help me. Thanks in advance