# JQuery/Javascript conflict? - Show/Hide div based on select option not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, show-hide

I have a booking form that I want to add multiple attendants to based on the number from a select option.

I've got this working on it's own here - https://jsfiddle.net/dentjames/7buxvd87/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

jQuery(function () {
    var $blocks = $('.block');
    $('#choices').change(function () {
        $blocks.slice(0, +this.value || 1).show();
        $blocks.slice(+this.value || 1).hide();
    }).change()
})

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <select id="choices">
        <option value="">Please choose number of children</option>
        <option value="1">1 Child</option>
        <option value="2">2 Children</option>
        <option value="3">3 Children</option>
        <option value="4">4 Children</option>
        <option value="5">5 Children</option>
    </select>
    <div id="block-1" class="block">
             <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text"><br><strong>First child</strong></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
          <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* First Name:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cfname" type="text" id="Child First Name" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* Surname:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="csname" type="text" id="Child Surname" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Sex:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <select name="csex" size="1" id="Child Sex">
              <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
              <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
            </select>
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* Date of Birth:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cdob" type="text" id="Child Date of Birth" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" nowrap class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Age at time of booking:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cage" type="text" id="Child age at time of booking" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Current school:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cschool" type="text" id="Child current school" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <div id="block-2" class="block">
                <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text"><br><strong>Second child</strong></div>
            </td>
        </tr>

             <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* First Name:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cfname" type="text" id="Child First Name" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* Surname:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="csname" type="text" id="Child Surname" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Sex:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <select name="csex" size="1" id="Child Sex">
              <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
              <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
            </select>
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* Date of Birth:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cdob" type="text" id="Child Date of Birth" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" nowrap class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Age at time of booking:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cage" type="text" id="Child age at time of booking" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Current school:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cschool" type="text" id="Child current school" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <div id="block-3" class="block">
             <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text"><br><strong>Third child</strong></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* First Name:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cfname" type="text" id="Child First Name" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* Surname:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="csname" type="text" id="Child Surname" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Sex:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <select name="csex" size="1" id="Child Sex">
              <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
              <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
            </select>
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* Date of Birth:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cdob" type="text" id="Child Date of Birth" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" nowrap class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Age at time of booking:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cage" type="text" id="Child age at time of booking" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Current school:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cschool" type="text" id="Child current school" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <div id="block-4" class="block">
              <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text"><br><strong>Forth child</strong></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
               <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* First Name:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cfname" type="text" id="Child First Name" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* Surname:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="csname" type="text" id="Child Surname" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Sex:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <select name="csex" size="1" id="Child Sex">
              <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
              <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
            </select>
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* Date of Birth:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cdob" type="text" id="Child Date of Birth" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" nowrap class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Age at time of booking:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cage" type="text" id="Child age at time of booking" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Current school:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cschool" type="text" id="Child current school" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <div id="block-5" class="block">
             <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text"><br><strong>Fifth child</strong></div>
            </td>
        </tr>

                <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* First Name:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cfname" type="text" id="Child First Name" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* Surname:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="csname" type="text" id="Child Surname" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Sex:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <select name="csex" size="1" id="Child Sex">
              <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
              <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
            </select>
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">* Date of Birth:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cdob" type="text" id="Child Date of Birth" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" nowrap class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Age at time of booking:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cage" type="text" id="Child age at time of booking" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="left" class="bodytext1">
                <div align="left" class="text">Current school:</div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <div align="left"> <span class="text"><font color="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="cschool" type="text" id="Child current school" size="40">
          </font></span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

But when I incorporate it to the main form, it doesn't work. I'm sure there's some conflict with the existing javascript and maybe some issues with the php.

The whole form can be viewed here:
http://whizzkidsclub.co.uk/horsham_bookingform_multiple.php

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Jason using `//` instead of `http:`/`https:` is valid see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http. It is called a a Protocol Relative URL and avoids a http/https issue.

Comment: TIL. It didn't work when I opened the file directly in my browser, but it works when I put it on a server and access it through the server. Thanks!

Comment: @James. The url which you have provided - the controls of first child, second child etc are outside the div#block-1, div#block-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the url (whizkidsclub...), the div(s) with id block-1, block-2 etc does not contain any element(s). The controls of first child, second child etc are outside the div(s).
[image]

Move your controls to the correct div(s) and it should start working

---

**Edit** As Jason pointed out the issue is that div cannot be a direct child of table element. So one way to fix this would be to use nested tables. That is change `<div id='block-1'>` to `<table id='block-1'>`. That said I'm sure there must be a better way...

This fix is demonstrated [here](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/7buxvd87/2/).

Comment: View the source. They look good there, but the browser pulls them out like that when it renders the page.

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing this out. I think one of the option, then, is to use nested tables...

Answer (score 1):

Your `div`'s (with the `block-*` `id`'s) are getting pulled out of the `table` by the browser and inserted just before the `table`. They're empty up there. I don't think `div`'s are allowed as immediate children of a `table`. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/f9t4qqmw/

Source:

```
<table>
    <div>
        <tr><td>1234</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abcd</td></tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

Inspected:

```
<div></div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1234</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abcd</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```