# jQuery is not working in any browser

Tags: jquery

This is my jquery code, which I have inside of `app.js`:

```
$(".spoiler p").hide();
$(".spoiler").append("<button>Reveal Spoiler!</button>");
```

I linked it in html like this:

```
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

But it is not working...please tell me what to do?

Comment: A little more info needed. What's in app.js? Where are you putting the script elements?

Comment: Try including `app.js` after **jQuery**. In addition make sure to use **jQuery** after the DOM has finished loading (`$(function(){ // Code here. });`)

Comment: the above code is app.js file

Comment: So you have to include `app.js` after jQuery, else it won't know what `$` means!

Comment: Could you open the development console and see if there are any error messages showing up there? Instructions on how to open the console are available [for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en#opening-the-console) and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console) (you can Google for other browsers).

Comment: file://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
app.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: For future reference, you need to define "not working." You will get an answer much moe quickly, with fewer questions posed to you in the comments. Pertinent code, _in context_ is always good, too.

Answer (score 2):

## Definite issue number 1:

Your script, `app.js`, is using jQuery, which hasn't loaded at the time of of its execution. `app.js` must be loaded *after* the jQuery files.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

## Definite issue number 2:

Your use of the common internet scheme synax (*CISS*) (`//:`) is good in production because it allows the file to be loaded by whatever scheme the originating page was loaded. In cases where your site may be loaded via *either* `http` *or* `https`, for example, you don't have to do any special coding to figure out whether you should use `http` or `https` to load the external files. The browser uses whatever was used to load the page, and you don't get mixed security warnings.

The problem, however, is that you appear (based on your comments) to be loading the originating page via the `file://` protocol--that is, locally. As such, the browser is attempting to load the two jQuery files locally as well because the CISS you used instructs the browser to use the same scheme as the originating page.

If you need to use CISS, you'll need to develop while serving your pages from a server (there are several options for running a server on your local machine for development purposes).

If, however, you are not ever going to mix security schemes in your production system, then the simplest solution is to load the external files via either `http` or `https` instead of allowing the browser to determine it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

## *Possible* issue number 3:

Your script, `app.js`, is executing before the elements you're searching for are present. The script tag for file `app.js` should be placed at the bottom of your document, and/or the code inside of `app.js` should be wrapped in `$(document).ready()`, or the shortcut of `$()`:

```
$(function () {
    $(".spoiler p").hide();
    $(".spoiler").append("<button>Reveal Spoiler!</button>");
});
```

## Bonus info

**This is not related to the problem at hand. Just a code critique with advice**

Re-querying the DOM for the same elements can get quite weighty. Rather than doing so:

Either store a reference to the elements and use that when needed:

```
$(function () {
    var spoilers = $(".spoiler");

    spoilers.find("p").hide();
    spoilers.append("<button>Reveal Spoiler!</button>");
});
```

Or, use jQuery's chaining:

```
$(function () {
    $(".spoiler")
        .append("<button>Reveal Spoiler!</button>")
        .find("p")
            .hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load your page in a local development environment (i.e. `file://`), then the implicit path `//` does not work and you have to explicitly declare the origin (i.e. `http://`).

To know more why, read: [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http).