# Why have all my d3 bl.ocks disappeared from bl.ocks.org?

Tags: d3.js

I've just added a new d3 block, to discover all the graphics have disappeared from my existing blocks: https://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders. The text is still there, and the code, but not the graphics. They were working fine last week.

This is not a normal SO question but I don't know who else to ask.

Given that the only block of mine left standing is the block "How to make a block", and that this does not include any links to my personal or professional site, I assume such links are a no-go on bl.ocks (not that I can see this rule anywhere). And I assume my blocks have been taken down for this transgression.

I've removed the links in the hope that this is the problem. Can someone reinstate them? If this isn't the problem, can anyone advise what is? Thanks...

Comment: Do your gists remain the same? This is probably just a glitch in bl.ocks, let's wait some time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The gists are identical - untouched till this morning when I stripped out all the links in case I was being blocked deliberately. Really alarmed they've all gone!

Comment: For all your bl.ocks, the console error is "d3 is not defined". Your link is: <script type="text/javascript" src=" http ://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>. I believe it should be https, not http. Like this: <script src=" https ://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script> (I had to add a space after http, for showing up here in the comments).

Comment: Thank you - I've updated them to https and it's worked. I find it really odd that it worked last week though!

Comment: If you go to  http**s**://, you can't load scripts via http,  If you got to http://, you can load scripts via http or https.  You really should be using `src="//d3js.org/d3.v2.js"`, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Answer (score 12):

bl.ocks.org is now permanently redirecting to Gist. Here are a [few](https://twitter.com/smtology/status/1603290140344029184) [tweets](https://twitter.com/currankelleher/status/1603121383516487680) [about](https://twitter.com/stevage1/status/1604693882179973121) [it](https://twitter.com/aboutaaron/status/1603884431512858624) starting from 15 Dec 2022.

However there is a clone of it up and running as of June 2023: `https://blocks.roadtolarissa.com/` which seems to duplicate all of the bl.ocks.org features.

For example [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/842e41b2ac0ff702a0a04dc6e48dca92/):

```
https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/842e41b2ac0ff702a0a04dc6e48dca92/
```

Now redirects to [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/micahstubbs/842e41b2ac0ff702a0a04dc6e48dca92/):

```
https://gist.github.com/micahstubbs/842e41b2ac0ff702a0a04dc6e48dca92/
```

But the full block can still be seen [here](https://blocks.roadtolarissa.com/micahstubbs/842e41b2ac0ff702a0a04dc6e48dca92/):

```
https://blocks.roadtolarissa.com/micahstubbs/842e41b2ac0ff702a0a04dc6e48dca92/
```

If there are any better alternatives or if these links die, please let me know and I will update the answer. :)

**Update:** Removed mention of `https://bl.ockss.org/`

Comment: Thank you for sharing. It's like the end of an era... Learning and using d3 will never be the same. As of June 2023, `https://bl.ockss.org/` is no longer running.

Comment: Cheers, have updated my answer

Comment: That site generates this when trying to access it with Firefox:

"Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead

Firefox detected an issue and did not continue to blocks.roadtolarissa.com. The website is either misconfigured or your computer clock is set to the wrong time.".

(My computer time is not misconfigured and access to other https sites works without problems).

Comment: @magjac nice catch, looks like the cert's expired. Have raised an issue on [Github](https://github.com/1wheel/roadtolarissa/issues/8)