# HTTPS > Bootstrap > Carousel - Images not showing over https

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, https, carousel

I am trying to create a boostrap carousel in my wordpress website.

The code is:

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div> <!-- Carousel -->
```

The boostrap jscript libaries are all loaded correctly via https sources.

The issue is that only images from http and not https sources show. In the example above, Image one fails (HTTPS) Image two and three work (HTTP).

As my site is hosted wholly in https, it means no images show when I link to them within my theme file.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Just download the images and upload them on your wordpress media library. That way, the images will be loaded from an HTTPS server too which will get rid of the http issue.

Comment: Hi Andrew.  Thank you for the feedback but that proposed solution will not work.  The issue is no that images are not being served via https but that the carousel cannot display images that are.

Comment: If the images are loaded from an https server, the carousel will load them Nathan. Right now, they aren't loaded as loading http content on https is a security risk.

Comment: Your placeholder image doesn't have any image extension

Comment: Hi Andrew.  Again thank you for the feedback but you are missing the point.  HTTP images are SHOWING UP it is the HTTPS images that are not.  All that loading from the media uploader will do (which is bad practice as theme images should be loaded from the theme folder) is to change the page to a green padlock from an amber one warning their are insecure elements.

Comment: Hi @Deeptichipdey thank you for the feedback.  The placeholder does not require an extension it is a specialist tool for enerating placeholders and to be clear it is working.  It only fails on the switch from http to https.

Comment: It'd be easier to work with a link. Could you provide us with one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by reducing the file size and compression method of the images to be used.  The code remains the same, save for the links which are now relative links to the images in the themes folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the article "[How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)" explains:

> If your website delivers HTTPS pages, all active mixed content delivered via HTTP on this pages will be blocked by default.

1st solution (ibid):

> The best strategy to avoid mixed content blocking is to serve all the content as HTTPS instead of HTTP.

2nd solution: You can try to use [relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/550073/6263942) without `http:` or `https:`. For example: //stackoverflow.com/questions/37629071