# Handling 404s while loading cached scripts using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I want to load a JS file using `jQuery` (for reasons out of scope of this post). I would like the cache to be used if available. Also I cannot set the global ajax `cache` setting to `true` (again for reasons out of scope). This rules out my using the `getScript` method So, per [jQuery's website](https://jsfiddle.net/15kozdpf/4/) I did the following:

```
$(function() {

  options = {
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    // scheme-less URI.
    url: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min1.js",//<--- 404
    success: function() {
      console.log("yes")
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("error")
    },
    always: function() {
      console.log("always")
    },
    statusCode: {
      404: function() {
       console.log("404")
        }
    }
  };
  var $d = jQuery.ajax(options);  
});
```

Now this works well in all cases except when the script request returns a 404, none of the error or fail methods get called.

I can force it to get called by applying a timeout , but I dont want to.
Why are the error handling methods not getting called?

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/15kozdpf/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug in jQuery 1.

If you remove the `dataType: "script",` everything works (regardless the URL you request).

Another option - upgdate to jQuery 2:
https://jsfiddle.net/6asrte12/

Comment: Thanks, 2.x did work. Pity we still need to support IE9/10 so cant use it for work :(

Comment: jQuery 2.x **support** IE9/10... you should double check

Comment: Typo, we have to also support IE8, so per jQuery : "If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.12."  yea i know.. its bad

Comment: yes, if you still need to support IE8 you have a problem.

Comment: however - i really don't think the other answer gives you the solution for every url. You should check it...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **https:** before the URL. It works for me

```
**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/15kozdpf/3/
```

Comment: You changed the url completely and it's not from the same domain. This is the new URL you have: `https//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min1.js` (you are missing the `:` there...)