# using http https or // for referencing a file in link or script tags

Tags: html

When referencing a file in my index.html file like this(using a link tag):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"/>
```

or using script tags to reference a file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/d3.js"></script>
```

**Is it best practice to write it like this: 

`//dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css` 
 
as opposed to 

 `http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css` 

 or 

`https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css`.**

My understanding is that this way whether a user visits the index.html page with http or https that is the protocol that will be used when for the referenced file. I am just wondering what is best practice?

Copy from my code for reference:

```
<!-- use //dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css instead of 


href="dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css" -- will look on smae server
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://192.168.99.100/lte_data_day_summary/dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"

href="/dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://192.168.99.100/dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"

href="//dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css" -- this works -- use this one 
NO ERROR 

href="///dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css" -- this works 
NO ERROR 

href="////dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css" -- this even works 
NO ERROR 

-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"/>
```

Found a related Q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends..

**- Updated -**

**Externally**: http or https included is the best practice. Biggest concern being most sites are moving towards SSL and having mixed or unresolved content will surely come back to haunt you.

**Internally**: relative path as described at the bottom is the best method.

---

Externally:

```
http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css
```

and

```
https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css
```

---

**Internally**

I use the the path versus full address in case a sites name is changed. It makes it a whole lot easier not having to back track.

This is of course only when I am hosting the file on the same site.

It should look more like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dc.js/css/dc.css"/>
```

or using script tags to reference a file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dc.js/js/d3.js"></script>
```

---

**Note:**

- no forward slash means it is located in the same folder you are loading the page from.
- single forward slash means it is in the root folder of the site located on the same server.
- double-infinite forward slashes means external file. Thats why there are no errors on your external links using 2 or more forward slashes.

Answer (score -1):

When you writing url without protocol (`http` or `https`) then it takes protocol automatic according to your url.

*Of course, if you’re viewing the file locally (not from server), it’ll try to request the file with the `file://` protocol.

such url example is

```
file:///D:/test.html
```

If you are trying to browse from your local server or your website then

`http://localhost/yourproject/test.html`

or

`http://www.example.com/test.html`

then it will take `http` protocol as i written above in first paragraph.

**Why to write url without protocol ?**

Because it may possible some websites don't need `https` protocol when it's launch. but later it may require due to security concern. so when website owner is not sure to convert to secure protocol, in such cases you can write this pattern to avoid further coding changes.