# Mixed Content with Pelican

Tags: https, cloudflare, pelican

> TL;DR
>
> My Pelican [blog](https://nonatomiclabs.com) is served through HTTPS but CSSs are not loaded because of "mixed content", even though they appear in the page source as HTTPS.

### Context

I have a Pelican blog hosted on GitHub pages. I have a CNAME record for a custom domain to point to this blog.

### The aim

I'm trying to achieve serving this blog with HTTPS, which is possible [with CloudFlare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/secure-and-fast-github-pages-with-cloudflare/) (GitHub support told me it's the only solution at the moment).

### The problem

After setting everything as indicated, I can access my blog securely but CSSs are not loaded because they are indicated as mixed content.

[image: Console errors]

However, when I look at the page source, all CSSs should be served with HTTPS (as it's included with protocol-relative URLs):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...
    <link href="//nonatomiclabs.github.io/theme/css/ipython.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//nonatomiclabs.github.io/theme/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//nonatomiclabs.github.io/theme/css/local.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//nonatomiclabs.github.io/theme/css/pygments.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

I have tried setting Pelican `SITEURL` variable to both `//nonatomiclabs.github.io` and `https://nonatomiclabs.github.io` and this does not change anything (so the problem is not due to the use of protocol-relative URLs).

CloudFlare also has an "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" feature which is supposed to get rid/reduce mixed content problems but does not help in my case.

### Questions

1. How is it possible that the browser (both Chrome and Safari at least) shows the page source with HTTPS or protocol-relative URLs but that those seem not to be respected?
2. Who is "responsible" for the problem? Pelican, CloudFlare, the browser, etc.?
3. How to solve the problem?

---

If one needs to see the code:

- the website is served at https://nonatomiclabs.com
- the source code can be found at https://github.com/nonatomiclabs/nonatomiclabs.github.io

  - the `source` branch contains the Pelican source
  - the `master` branch contains the published site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. It's most likely not that browsers aren't respecting the HTTPS URLs, but that the domain re-direction is resulting in unencrypted HTTP links.
2. Some combination of GitHub Pages, CloudFlare, and associated domain re-direction is most likely the cause of the problem.
3. Potential solutions follow below.

First, try explicitly prepending the static asset links with `https:` inside your [HTML](https://github.com/nonatomiclabs/nonatomiclabs.github.io/blob/master/index.html#L10) instead of relying on the `SITEURL` setting and see whether anything changes.

Second, the only resources that are failing are those that begin with https://nonatomiclabs.github.io — it seems that requests to that domain are being re-directed to https://www.nonatomiclabs.com, and that re-direction could be the cause of the problem. Try using a domain that does not re-direct. For example:

```
<link href="https://www.nonatomiclabs.com/theme/css/local.css" rel="stylesheet">
[...]
```

For what it's worth, for my personal [Justin Mayer](https://justinmayer.com) site, my base.html template's CSS links look similar to [yours](https://github.com/nonatomiclabs/nonatomiclabs.github.io/blob/source/theme/templates/base.html#L10). I set my `SITEURL` setting to https://justinmayer.com in my publishconf.py settings file, and the resulting output contains proper, fully-qualified links (i.e., not protocol-relative links) that do not yield mixed content warnings.

As an aside, [protocol-relative URLs are considered to be an anti-pattern](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), as they are essentially obsolete in a world of ubiquitous TLS, particularly when [Google Chrome 68 marks all unencrypted HTTP requests as insecure](https://www.techradar.com/news/from-july-chrome-will-flag-all-unencrypted-websites-as-not-secure) this coming July.)

As another side note, there are indications that [GitHub Pages might soon support HTTPS](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/156#issuecomment-366542067), so you may eventually be able to serve your site over HTTPS without CloudFlare.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to have HTTPS URLs already, by setting SITEURL="https://nonatomiclabs.github.io" but it did not help

Comment: Also, if you go on the actual website and look at the source code of the page, it seems that all CSSs are included with HTTPS. That’s really the thing I don’t understand

Comment: I hardcoded the URLs in the base.html but it doesn’t seem to change anything :(

Comment: The only resources that are failing are those that begin with `https://nonatomiclabs.github.io` — it seems that requests for resources at that domain are being re-directed to `https://www.nonatomiclabs.com`, and that re-direction could be the cause of the problem. I updated the answer to account for this possibility.

Comment: I ended up changing CloudFlare's SSL option from "Full" to "Flexible" and it works. I'd be curious to know of another way to solve the issue but I spent enough time on it and I guess I'll eventually migrate to GitHub-managed HTTPS anyway. Thank you for your quick answer anyway and thank you for Pelican! :)