# how to reference angular.min.js file in my app.js file?

Tags: angularjs

I have two files in my code folder: `app.js`, and `index.html`.

```js
// MODULE
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);

// CONTROLLERS
// Create the controller function and register it with the module
angularApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.name = 'ABC';
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="angularApp">

<head>
  <title>Introduction to AngularJS</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      font-size: 1.1em;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- load angular via CDN -->
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AngularJS</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="container">

    <div ng-controller="mainController">

      <h1>Hello world!</h1>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am getting the following error in `app.js` file

> ERROR: 'angular' is not defined.[no-undef]
>
> for the line:
>
> var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);

But the web page runs fine in Chrome and displays everything properly.
But I am not understanding why this error comes for `angular` object although `angular.min.js` is included in `index.html`.

Comment: Have your imported the angular module to your app.js?

Comment: Are you getting any other error in your console.window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Comment: did you check your browser console if the angular.min.js is getting downloaded or not?

Comment: I am just learning angularjs through www.udemy.com and am replicating their video content. Infact, I have downloaded their video code. Hence I am using brackets editor like they have done. So how to import the angular module in app.js? I mean do I still have to import it there as the angular.min.js is included in index.html.

Comment: are you running the same code which you have mentioned in the question, or have you changed anything. You also need to make sure that you are running it as a http url, as directly opening the html file using browser will not work.

Comment: I am running it using the brackets editor's live preview option.The browser url is" http://127.0.0.1:54962/index.htm#". Please note that as I have mentioned before, my web page runs fine..but i am getting the error in the brackets editor. Also now I have downloaded angular.min.js locally and have included it in my index.html. It is also referenced before my app.js in the html file. Live preview displays the web page properly. Also when i click on the Sources tab in the browser console, the angular.min.js is downloaded there. Only thing I can't get rid of the angular not defined error in app.js

Comment: Yes..I am running the same code that I mentioned..Only thing as you know, now I have downloaded the angular.min.js file locally and have included it in the html file.